# CYTOSCAPE JS dijkstra algorithm with preset layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, traversal, dijkstra, cytoscape.js

I'm using the cytoscape.js graph library on a website I am creating here:
http://consulting.citi.co.uk/

My query is, does anyone have an example using Dijkstra algorithm or Traversing to show multiple relationships on node select / hover?  I have made it work using the demo, but it only traces one route on load:
[How to highlight the path between two nodes in CYTOSCAPE JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011729/how-to-highlight-the-path-between-two-nodes-in-cytoscape-js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand.  Do you mean you want to show the directly connected relationships?  In that case, it's even simpler than Dijkstra or BFS:  You can use the neighbourhood: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/traversing/eles.neighborhood

Or maybe you're looking for something more along the lines of the BFS demo? http://jsbin.com/gist/7e2f4d29ff7ef1a1bba5?js,output

Comment: I have used neighbourhood on the current example, but what I would like to do is trace back to a node 3 or 4 nodes away using existing edges (without creating a direct link, as that looks messy).

Comment: If you're looking for a path between two particular nodes, you should use A* (`eles.aStar()`).