# Highlight actual path in tree as given data in Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to Highlight all nodes and paths on click from a node to root.

I found a partial example in this link - [How to highlight the path between two nodes in CYTOSCAPE JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011729/how-to-highlight-the-path-between-two-nodes-in-cytoscape-js/).

The code in above link uses Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path. But I need the actual path taken, as given in data.

For example, consider the following data:

```
nodes: [
    { data: { id: 'a' } },
    { data: { id: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'd' } },
    { data: { id: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'f' } },
    { data: { id: 'g' } }
  ], 

edges: [
    { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'ac', weight: 2, source: 'a', target: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'bd', weight: 3, source: 'b', target: 'd' } },
    { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'cg1', weight: 5, source: 'c', target: 'g' } },
    { data: { id: 'gc1', weight: 6, source: 'g', target: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'cg2', weight: 7, source: 'c', target: 'g' } },
    { data: { id: 'gf', weight: 8, source: 'g', target: 'f' } }
  ]
```

Using the code in link, tree highlight works like this if source is a, and target is f.

[Tree Highlight with Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D77Z.jpg)

If anyone can help me trace and highlight the path as given in data, it would be very helpful.

Comment: The path Dijkstra gives *is* the path taken from `a` to `f`.  Please clarify your question.  It's not clear what you want.  You have example data, so please indicate what you would expect as output for that dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to print out the shortest path using the A* method. Altering it for Dijkstra's algorithm I would probably for example implement the ffg:

```
var dijkstra = cy.elements().dijkstra('#e', function(){
  return this.data('weight');
});

var pathToJ = dijkstra.pathTo( cy.$('#j') ); 

                for (i = 0,j=0; i < pathToJ.nodes().size(),j<pathToJ.edges().size(); i++,j++) {
                    console.log('Nodes Size - '+ pathToJ.nodes().size());
                    console.log('Edges Size - '+ pathToJ.edges().size());
                    console.log('Node - \t' + pathToJ.nodes()[i].data('id'));
                    console.log('edge - \t' + pathToJ.edges()[j].data('id'));
                }
```

`pathTo(node)` returns a collection containing the shortest path from the source node to node.

If no weight function is defined, a constant weight of 1 is used for each edge.