# How would I find all paths between two nodes using cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a telecommunications mesh network graph where there are multiple path between multiple nodes.

I want to be able to select 2 nodes and highlight all inter connected nodes and edges that make up the paths between them.

How would you recommend I tackle this?

I've tried using aStar, then removing the nodes and edges and reiterating, however some paths share edges so that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight the path between two nodes in CYTOSCAPE JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011729/how-to-highlight-the-path-between-two-nodes-in-cytoscape-js)

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the paths between two nodes in Cytoscape.js you can use the following:

```
function findPaths(src,dest) {
    let successors = src.successors();
    let predecessors = dest.predecessors();
    return successors.intersection(predecessors);
}
```

This takes all of the nodes and edges from src and keeps only those that are also in the set of those leading to dest.

It does not enumerate the paths - it is just the full set of nodes and edges in the paths.

To actually enumerate all the individual possible paths (it can be a large number if you're dealing with a complex graph) you would do a depth first recursion on the results of this function. Each time dest is visited, you would display the path that led to the visit.